# How can I define label for items of a struct in Swift?

Tags: swift

This is my struct:

```
struct TestType {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}
```

I am looking to define a label for items inside this struct, almost like a label to give needed info about the item, like we can do for enums like this:

```
enum TestEnum {

    case name(String)
    case age(Int)
    
    var label: String {
        switch self {
        case .name:
            return "Name of person"
        case .age:
            return "Age of person"
        }
    }
    
    var value: Any {
        switch self {
        case .name(let string):
            return string
        case .age(let int):
            return int
        }
    }
}
```

So my goal is working on struct for defining a label kind computed property, like this:

```
let value: TestType = TestType(name: "Bob", age: 25)

let newValue1: String = value.name.label  // It should gave: "Name of person"
let newValue2: String = value.age.label   // It should gave: "Age of person"
```

How can I do this?

***My idea is simply using  tuple instead of `String` or `Int` like `(String, String)` or `(Int, String)`***

Comment: How would this label be consumed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution would be to not declare directly `name` & `age` as `String`/`Int`, but as a intermediary struct which can hold the label and the value:

```
struct Label<T> {
    var value: T
    var label: String
}
```

Then, you can have:

```
struct TestType {
    var name: Label<String>
    var age: Label<Int>

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = Label(value: name, label: "Name of person")
        self.age = Label(value: age, label: "Age of person")
    }
}
```

And in use:

```
let test = TestType(name: "Bob", age: 25)
let nameValue = test.name.value
let nameLabel = test.name.label
let ageValue = test.age.value
let ageLabel = test.age.label
print(nameValue)
print(nameLabel)
print(ageValue)
print(ageLabel)
```

Output:

```
$>Bob
$>Name of person
$>25
$>Age of person
```